# How to redirect links from structure to another

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My site Permalinks structure is: `/%post_id%/%postname%/`

`/%post_id%/`
and
`/%post_id%/%postname%/`
are working correctly and showing the same content

I want to redirect every link with
`/%post_id%/ structure` 
to
`/%post_id%/%postname%/` structure without change Permalinks structure

Is there any way to do that using WordPress plugin or `htaccess` code?

Comment: In .htaccess the post name is unknown, so you can not do it from there. And asking for plugin recommendations is explicitly considered off-topic here; if you need to find a plugin, you need to go and do your research yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved using [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

[permalink settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRiEI.jpg)

[Redirections plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3wCE.jpg)